# Regex lookahead continue looking on each line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to locate URL's inside a string. Not just the first but any URL in a string or file. And ignore the URL from a regex replace query. I'm using a lookahead to locate any text followed by a http. But cannot figure out how to make the lookahead continue after the first http.

The regex `.*(?=(http))` will locate all the text until the first http in a string but how do I make it repeat until the end of the string. And how do I make it continue from after the match of the URL.

UPDATE:
In the text:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been abc http://www.cnn.com:the:2:3 the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer abc http://www.cnn.com:the:1 took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book

here I'm trying to skip all the url's and replace e.g. "the" with "123". But not inside a URL.

Comment: give your string input and your expected output to make it clear.

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using? Can't you just do multiple matches?

Comment: "*locate any text followed by a http*" doesn't sound like you want to locate single URLs. What do you really want?

Comment: If regex flavor is pcre, you can ignore/skip something by using [(*SKIP)(*F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28*SKIP%29-%28*SKIP%3ANAME%29) See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sV8lI7/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Jonny is correct! :) This regex does the job!

> http://\S*|(?:(?!http).)*

.. or almost does as expected. It split the input text into matches and put all the "http\S" in separate groups. But it don't skip the http's like the (*SKIP)(*F) the pcre flavor can.

UPDATE: found a solution that works in .NET. Using the match groups and checking if the 2nd group has any data.

> http://\S*|((?:(?!http).)*)

With (..) in the last regex group we can use the match.Groups. And !string.IsNullOrEmpty(group[1].Value) to get only the matches that don't contain a URL.

Comment: does anyone know if the .NET engine can do something like (*SKIP)(*F)?